# How to handle JWT expiry mechanism in native apps

Tags: android, react-native, django-rest-framework-jwt, jwt

I am building a hybrid app on React Native, We are using Django rest framework on the backend. We are using JWT for securing the app, the use case of the app involves storing sensitive information.

The problem is in JWT expiry. I need to hit an API with the accessToken to get a new token, this works fine and token won't expire if the user opens app every day, which is next to impossible.

Hence the user logs out every few days since by the time he opens the app the token is expired. Is there a better way to handle this? Facebook app, google pay app never log out the user.

I tried keeping a variable associated with a user suggesting he is a mobile app user and thus never expiring that token unless he logs out or done so explicitly, but I've had reviews that's a dangerous method.

Comment: Do you want a solution for React-Native approach or native Android?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use access_token to get a new one!
The proper way is to give a refresh_token to the user each time you issue an access_token.
refresh_token is a long-lived one-time use token which is used to get a new access_token.
You can search to learn more about refresh_token.